# datagridview mousehover event how to determine which column you are on

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I want to display a tooltip when I mousehover over a column header on my datagridview control (dgrv1).  Currently, I can do the following, which works -- but -- my datagridview has several columns (and a lot of text for each tooltip), so I would like to call a method from the mousehover event.  My problem is that I don't know how to capture which column I am hovering over to pass in to the method.  Interestingly, the mousehover event picks the correct column in my current scenario:

```
private void dgrv1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    dgrv1.Columns[1].ToolTipText = "column 1";
    dgrv1.Columns[2].ToolTipText = "column 2";
    dgrv1.Columns[3].ToolTipText = "column 3";
}
```

If I mousehover over column 1 -- the tooltiptext for column 1 gets displayed, and the same for columns 2, 3, ...  But instead of listing 50 columns (which the tooltips would contain quite a bit of text) in the mousehover event here, how could I just call a method from the mousehover event and pass in the correct column number?

Comment: Are you showing one and the same tooltip text for a specific column, or it's dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign `ToolTipText` property of your columns in hover event. you simply can assign them using `Designer` or if you want when you load data or load event of form using such code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    c.ToolTipText = string.Format("Column {0}", c.Index + 1);
}
```

You can also assign a text to `ToolTip` property of a cell:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToolTipText = "Some text"
```

But if you want to know what is the column and row that mouse is hover on it, you can use [`HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = this.dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    var info = this.dataGridView1.HitTest(p.X, p.Y);

    //You can use this values
    //info.ColumnX
    //info.RowY
    //info.ColumnIndex
    //info.RowIndex
}
```

Pay attention that `RowIndex` is -1 for column header cells and `ColumnIndex` is -1 for row header cells.

Comment: The designer -- I guess that would be the easiest way - and yes in this project I could use the designer since the columns will never change. I can add the column in the columns collection of the datagridview properties which has a spot for tooltips.  But I do like the var p, var info suggestion.  That would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with the DataGridViewCellEventArgs:

```
private void DataGridView_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  e.ColumnIndex //column
  e.RowIndex    //row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim grvScreenLocation As Point = DGVRejected999Clm.PointToScreen(DGVRejected999Clm.Location)
            Dim tempX As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.X - grvScreenLocation.X + DGVRejected999Clm.Left
            Dim tempY As Integer = DataGridView.MousePosition.Y - grvScreenLocation.Y + DGVRejected999Clm.Top
            Dim hit As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = DGVRejected999Clm.HitTest(tempX, tempY)
            cellX = hit.RowIndex
            cellY = hit.ColumnIndex
            Dim col =DGVRejected999Clm.Columns(cellY).Name
            If col="INTERNAL_STATUS" THEN
            Dim value =DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).Value.ToString
               If Value="E" THEN
                   DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="999 ERROR"
                    Else If Value="F" Then
                      DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="EJECTED BY EDI SIMPLIFIED"
                    Else If value="N" Then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="NEW CLAIM"
                    Else If value="R" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="REGENERATED- WAITING FOR SUBMISSION"
                     Else If value="S" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="SUBMITTED"
                    Else If value="K" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="999 ACKNOWLEDGED"
                    Else If value="D" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="999 DENIED. RESUBMISSION REQUIRED"
                       Else If value="A" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="277 ACCEPTED"
                     Else If value="J" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="277 REJECTED"
                    Else If value="Q" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="REQUEUED"

                    Else If value="M" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="SEND TO PM-REJECTED by Payer"

                    Else If value="X" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="SEND TO PM-REJECTED by EDI Simplified"

                     Else If value="T" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="999 ACKNOWLEDGED-Payer dont support 277 - Payer Accepted"


                      Else If value="V" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="999 ACKNOWLEDGED-Payer dont support 277 - Payer Rejected"

                    Else If value="G" then
                    DGVRejected999Clm.Rows(cellX).Cells(cellY).ToolTipText="Rejected Claim - Review Required"



               End If
           End If
```